# How to retrieve all child nodes in a single query using lxml & XPATH

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml

This is my xml data

```
<location>
   <city>
      <name> New York</name>
      <type>non-capital</type>
   </city>

   <city>
        <name> London</name>
        <type>capital</type>
   </city>
</location>
```

using lxml & python

```
from lxml import etree as ET

parser = ET.XMLParser(recover=True)

tree = ET.fromstring(xml_data,parser)
print(tree.xpath('//city//name/text() | //city//type/text()'))
```

The above code works but i'd like an nested-array description as `[['New York','non-capital'],['London','capital']]`

What would be the accurate xpath query/combination of queries/loops to get the above?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is one possible way :

```
.......
result = []
for city in tree.xpath('//city'):
    result.append([city.find('name').text, city.find('type').text])

print(result)
# output :
#[[' New York', 'non-capital'], [' London', 'capital']]
```

Answer (score 2):

List comprehension solution:

```
xml_data='''<location>
   <city>
      <name> New York</name>
      <type>non-capital</type>
   </city>
   <city>
        <name> London</name>
        <type>capital</type>
   </city>
</location>'''

from lxml import etree as ET

parser = ET.XMLParser(recover=True)

tree = ET.fromstring(xml_data,parser)
print(tree.xpath('//city'))


cities = [[c.text for c in n if c.tail] for n in tree.xpath('//city')]
```

Results in:

```
[[' New York', 'non-capital'], [' London', 'capital']]
```

Comment: `[[c.text for c in n] for n in tree.xpath('//city')]` works fine, what does c.tail do?

Comment: Its just my habit that I have, but in your case not needed. lxml can have normal text and so-called tail text. More [here](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html)

Comment: Keep getting this error-ValueError: Unicode strings with encoding declaration are not supported. Please use bytes input or XML fragments without declaration.